# Should I compile GCC with latest version?

Tags: gcc

I have to compile 3 versions of `gcc`, say `9`, `10` and `11`.
My system `gcc` is version `8` (let's say).

Question : do I have any advantage on compiling `gcc-v9` with `gcc-v8`, `gcc-10` with `gcc-v9` and `gcc-v11` with `gcc-v10` ?

Or I don't have any advantage and I can compile them all the `gcc-v8` ?

Thank you for pointing out some directions for further research.

Comment: Let's imagine you are not compiling gcc, but some other software you know nothing about. Do you have any advantage when compiling with `gcc8` vs `gcc9` vs `gcc10` vs `gcc11`?

Comment: I might have some advantage if the software I know nothing about can use the features available on the latest versions, I would say.

Comment: Newer versions have both new bugs and new bug fixes. (and new features/new optimization tricks). I would speculate though that all compilers can be compiled by some of the previous versions and then by self. After one more iteration the resulting binary should be stable.

Comment: So, no matter how old is the compiler used in the compiling process, it should be able to compile the latest version with it's full features - for example, I could compile `gcc-v12` with `gcc-v4` and then obtain the same performance when compiling code with a `gcc-v12` compiled with a `gcc-v11`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC has a "bootstrap" build process.  So when you try to build gcc-11 with only gcc-8 installed, it will build a temporary "stage 1" version of gcc-11 using gcc-8, then compile gcc-11 again using gcc-11-stage1.  Thus no matter what you start with, the version of gcc-11 that comes out of the build process was effectively compiled with itself.

So all that matters is that gcc-8, or whatever "system compiler" was previously installed, is able to build a stage1 version of gcc-11 that runs well enough to compile the stage 2 version.  It doesn't matter whether your system compiler is good at optimizing, and gcc's source code is deliberately written to use a fairly minimal set of language feature (at least for stage 1), so you are not likely to run into trouble with your system compiler having missing or buggy support for obscure corners of the language.  Historically, the "system compiler" was often not gcc at all, but some compiler provided by the computer vendor or an unrelated third party, and so one couldn't rely much on its quality; gcc was designed with that in mind.

Theoretically your system compiler could have a bug which miscompiles gcc-11-stage1 in such a way that it appears to work, but itself miscompiles stage2.  This is unlikely, and it's even less likely that it would happen in a way that wasn't obvious (e.g. the stage2 compiler simply segfaulting).  If worried, there's an option to have stage2 build a stage3 compiler, and then check that both versions are identical.  So as long as the build completes, you can be pretty confident that the final installed compiler is fine and unaffected by bugs in the original system compiler.  (All that said, a reference to Ken Thompson's "[Reflections on Trusting Trust](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/358198.358210)" is obligatory here.)

So in practice, you don't need to worry about the version of gcc used to build a new version.  Whatever you happen to have installed already, within reason, will be fine.